# Express.js: API URL and res.json, using request package from npm

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, express

I'm at wits end trying to figure out how to get my API to return a valid JSON object.

I'm currently using the following code to send a response:

```
res.json({ foo: 'bar', secret: 'code' });
```

I have also tried:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar', secret: 'code' }));
```

Both of the above methods work when I visit the API URL in browser. I get the expected:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "secret": "code"
}
```

On the other hand, I'm having trouble parsing the JSON response from URL (the example below uses the `request` package from `npm`):

```
request({
    url: API-URL,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
      console.log(body);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Using the above code, I get the following error response:

```
{
  "code": "ENOTFOUND",
  "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
  "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
  "hostname": <<Redacted>>,
  "host": <<Redacted>>,
  "port": 443
}
```

I've tried plugging in third-party API URLs and they work just fine (ie: Google Maps, and OpenWeatherAPI) so I'm pretty sure that I'm using `request` properly. I'm guessing there is a step I missed in setting up the API (or I'm doing something wrong)?

Testing my API URL in `https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/`, the formatted JSON object shows up but I also get the following regardless of how I set the response header and encoding:
`Error: Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.[Code 29, Structure 0]`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
The above is in a live web app and Express works properly otherwise (everything else in the application works fine, the JSON response just isn't playing nicely with `request` or jQuery.

Comment: Can you provide your server side code? It looks like you might not be doing a `server.listen();`

Comment: As @peteb pointed out, it seems like a problem with either express not starting properly or you have an error with your `request` call. I don't think it has anything to do with incorrectly formatted JSON.

Comment: In my app.js I have the following:

``server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);``

Express is starting properly (the API is only a part of the web app) and everything works live except for the request call. Navigating to the API URL works too. It just doesn't seem to work with any sort of request call.

Comment: You're providing a hostname that cannot be resolved. Check your URL or DNS configuration.

Comment: As @jcaron said, it could be your `API-URL` value that you're passing into your request opts `url` value.